# Xml Jaxb namespaces and attributes order

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, jaxb, attributes

I'm trying to parse Java object to Xml representation using JaxB (Jaxb2Marshaller). In one of element I have two namespaces and several attributes. Everything is alright, but first I got attributes and then come namespaces.
How to changes, or is it even possible to change order, so first I have namespaces and after it all attributes.

What I've got now

```
    <Element elementId="AB000000011" timeStamp="2018-12-04T18:48:52.535+02:00" version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.namespace.com/schemas/namespaceapi" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
```

What I 'd like to achieve

```
    <Element xmlns="http://www.namespace.com/schemas/namespaceapi" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" elementId="AB000000011" timeStamp="2018-12-04T18:48:52.535+02:00" version="2.0" >
```

Of course I can manage order of attributes with help of @XmlType#propOrder, but what is the way to do the similar thing with namespaces?

Comment: Namespaces are attributes too, and XML attributes are unordered, so any arbitrary order is valid. Why do you care about attribute order? XML doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to change the order but you can generate a brand new xml file  using what you have and select your order.

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();

    // Root Element
    Element root = document.createElement("Element");
    document.appendChild(root);

    // xmlns Element 
    Element xmlns = document.createElement("");
    root.appendChild(xmlns);

    // xmlns2 Element 
    Element xmlns2 = document.createElement("xmlns:ns2");
    root.appendChild(xmlns2);

    // Id Element 
    Element elementId = document.createElement("elementId");
    root.appendChild(elementId);

    // timeStamp Element 
    Element timeStamp = document.createElement("timeStamp");
    root.appendChild(timeStamp);

    // Version Element 
    Element version = document.createElement("version");
    root.appendChild(version);
```

than you can set the value with Xpath or Xstream(I dont know if this is right name) like this:

```
    // Version Element 
    Element estruturas = document.createElement("version");
    root.appendChild(version);
    version.setTextContent(xpathElement(document, "/Element*[@class='version']").getTextContent());
```

Hope I could help you.